# Session callback is not invoking after JWT callback

Tags: next.js13, next-auth

The problem is the code below is working perfectly till JWT callback , even consoling token i.e.
`//in JWT callback console.log(token)`
in JWT callback works , but session callback is not invoked after JWT callback

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next"
import Credentials from "next-auth/providers/credentials"

export const authOptions = {
    providers:[
        Credentials({
            name:"Credentials",
            credentials:{
                uid:{label:"uid",type:"text"},
                password:{label:"password",type:"text"}
            },
            async authorize(credentials,req){
                try{
                    return {
                        uid:123,
                        role:"user"
                    }
                }catch(e){
                    console.log(e)
                }
            }
        })
    ],
    secret:process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
    session:{
        jwt:true
    },
    callbacks:{
        async session({ session, user, token }) {
            console.log("this")
            console.log(session);
          
            if (token) {
              session.user.uid = token.uid;
              session.user.role = token.role;
            }
          
            return session;
          },
        async jwt({ token, user ,session}) {
            token.uid = user.uid;
            token.role = user.role;
            console.log(token);
            //working perfectly till here
            return token;
            },
        async signIn({account,profile,user}){
            if(account.provider === "credentials" && user){
                return true
            }
            return false
        }
    }
}

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions)
export {handler as GET,handler as POST}
```

i have even tried to direclty pass the token without modifying it in JWT , but still not working since session is not called.